# curl a URL with parameters using `-d`

Tags: url, curl, web

I have a url with some parameters like this:

http://cistrome.org/finder/site/result?did=1200&tf=AR&Gene_box=&all_gene=1&region_select=proximal&extend_bp_number=200&repeat_bp_number=150&primer=0

It works well in browser.

But when I tried to get the result by `curl` like this:

```
curl -d "did=1200%20tf=AR%20Gene_box=%20all_gene=1%20region_select=proximal%20extend_bp_number=200%20repeat_bp_number=150%20primer=0" http://cistrome.org/finder/site/result
```

It returns a message that `did` is not passed as the request.

If I use the url directly, it gives me the result like this:

```
curl http://cistrome.org/finder/site/result?did=1200&tf=AR&Gene_box=&all_gene=1&region_select=proximal&extend_bp_number=200&repeat_bp_number=150&primer=0
[1] 4931*emphasized text*
[2] 4932
[3] 4933
[4] 4934
[5] 4935
[6] 4936
[7] 4937
[2]   Done                    tf=AR
[3]   Done                    Gene_box=
[4]   Done                    all_gene=1
[5]   Done                    region_select=proximal
[6]-  Done                    extend_bp_number=200
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: You can just use the full URL. No need to separate the query string.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I tried use the full URL first, but it didn't work.

Comment: you should use a single quote to enclose the URL. Tried & Working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command instead :

```
curl 'http://cistrome.org/finder/site/result?did=1200&tf=AR&Gene_box=&all_gene=1&region_select=proximal&extend_bp_number=200&repeat_bp_number=150&primer=0'
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell interprets the ampersand as the end of a command that should run as a background process.  You can enclose the URL in quotes, or you can escape the ampersands with a backslash, like so:

```
curl http://cistrome.org/finder/site/result?did=1200\&tf=AR\&Gene_box=\&all_gene=1\&region_select=proximal\&extend_bp_number=200\&repeat_bp_number=150\&primer=0
```